# react native, Navigate screens on horizontal swipe

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app with a bottom navigation(using react navigation) the app has 4 screens and it works fine, i want to be add the functionality to navigate between screens on horizontal gestures(swiping right or left) just like instagram does(swiping left from feed will get you to chat screen), i looked all around and found nothing on how to do this !

**EDIT:** apparently react navigation has that option in creatematerialtoptabnavigator, it'll be a top navigation tab bar with the ability to swipe between screens, you can also change it's position from bottom or top which is what i did.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check out https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view ?

I find it easy to use and the documentation is very good

Comment: Thank you for the help, i found the answer and edited in case someone came into this.
What i have been looking for was already implemented in react-navigation, only it was in createMaterialTopTabNavigator and not createMaterialBottomTabNavigator, so basically i used createMaterialTopTabNavigator and changed its position to Bottom.